# Why shouldn't you always use Apache's event MPM instead of the worker MPM?

Tags: apache, events, concurrency, worker, apache2.4

`mpm_event` is like `mpm_worker` except that `mpm_event` manages all (non-SSL) KeepAlive connections with a separate, dedicated thread rather than having each thread manage each individual connection.  By giving and then keeping a dedicated thread for each KeepAlive connection, `mpm_worker` leaves that thread and its resources bound to that connection regardless of whether or not a request is being processed. `mpm_event` on the other hand, can lower system resource use in high concurrency environments by allowing the thread and its resources to be recycled back to the system once requests are complete.

It seems to me that in high concurrency, non-SSL environments where KeepAlive has long timeouts, `mpm_event` has the potential to make for a system that can handle a higher workload with equivalent resources than a system with the same resorces using `mpm_worker`. ***More importantly, it seems to me that in terms of resource use and features, `mpm_event` is at least as good as `mpm_worker`, if not better, in all circumstances.***

Despite my understanding that `mpm_event` is always at least as good and possibly better, my favorite Linux distributions default to using `mpm_worker` when installing Apache 2.4 from the repositories. This makes me wonder if my thinking is incomplete and if there is some technical reason I am missing to use `mpm_worker` rather than `mpm_event` in Apache 2.4.

**My question therefore is am I correct in saying `mpm_worker` is at least as good as `mpm_event`, if not better, in all circumstances, and (2) if not, what technical benefits are there to using `mpm_worker` in Apache 2.4?**

Answer (score 2):

There are two "advantages" I can think of.  Both are pretty obscure.

worker does not need to fight over a lock in each process to protect the list of keepalive connections. This means there are degenerate workloads that could see that lock contention at relatively low # of total clients and thus not benefit at all from the scalability of event.

secondly, some very obscure third-party modules might have subtle bugs under event in cases where things like async write completion means some callbacks happen on a "different" thread.   async write completion is what happens when a write to the client would block (client reading slowly) so the request is suspended and will be brought back to life on a new thread when the client socket is again writable.

Comment: it's really obscure  for me, especially the second point, and i have not been in touch with async write completion. I think about it as 3rd-party modules compatibility prblems temporarily. Thank you for answering this old question.